# How can I use react-native with php with fetch return data is always null

Tags: javascript, php, ios, json, react-native

My return is always null. i cant seems to get this to work. How can I use react-native with php with fetch json. anyone can help?

PHP

```php
$myArray = array();
$myArray['lat'] = $_POST['lat']; 
$myArray['lng'] = $_POST['lng'];
echo $_POST['lat'];
```

React-Native Fetch

```js
fetch(url, {
  method: 'post',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    lat: region.latitude,
    lng: region.longitude,
  }),
})
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseData) => {
    console.log(responseData);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.warn(error);
  })
  .done();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have to use file_get_contents('php://input') if not php cant see the data.

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

$myArray = array();
$myArray['lat'] = $json['lat']; 
$myArray['lng'] = $json['lng'];
$myArray['status'] = 'success';
echo json_encode($myArray);
```

Comment: have happend with me too .. still trying to figure out why i had to use `file_get_contents('php://input')` when we use `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` , do you have idea why this is happening ?

Comment: If I get it ill add answer here and let you know

Comment: Sure. Thanks alot! :)

Comment: The reason that you have to use `file_get_contents('php://input')` is because its not form data. It is passing in a raw body request there and so php doesn't know to parse that as JSON by default. You are passing in a JSON body and anytime you use something like that you will have to parse it that way.